# Sitecore ECM SubscribtionForm title

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2, sitecore-ecm

I'm using Sitecore 7.2 with ECM 2.1 and I want to use predefined `SubscriptionForm` but with my title, description, button text. I found in code that this information we can get like this

```
Util.GetFrontEndText("simple title");
```

But I cannot find where this fields (`simple title`, `email address`, etc.) are, so maybe somebody can help me to find where  I can change this fields values?

Answer (score 1):

FYI I found where this fields are.
Path is: /sitecore/system/Modules/E-mail Campaign Manager/Common Text